Combining two probability distributions together
I had an idea about creating a problem in which a coin is being flipped, but the probability of heads is random each flip. After reading about this online, I realize something like this might already exist under the name of "Beta-Binomial Distribution" (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta-binomial_distribution).
As I understand, in a Beta-Binomial Distribution, the coin is being flipped according to a Binomial Distribution, but the probability of heads is a random number from a Beta Distribution.
I thought to myself - is it possible to derive this using the laws of total probability? I tried to do this myself.
Here is the law of total probability:
$$
P(A) = \int P(A | B) \cdot f_B(b) \, db
$$
Here is the Binomial Distribution:
$$
P(X = k | p) = \binom{n}{k} p^k (1 - p)^{n - k}
$$
Here is the Beta Distribution and Beta Function:
$$
f(p; \alpha, \beta) = \frac{p^{\alpha - 1} (1 - p)^{\beta - 1}}{B(\alpha, \beta)}
$$
$$
B(\alpha, \beta) = \int_0^1 p^{\alpha - 1} (1 - p)^{\beta - 1} dp
$$
Now, we need to combine all these concepts together. Conceptually, what is the probability of $x=k$ given $p$ multiplied by the probability of observing $p$ ... integrated over all possible ways of this happening?
$$
P(X = k) = \int_0^1 P(X = k | p) f(p; \alpha, \beta) \, dp
$$
$$
P(X = k) = \int_0^1 \binom{n}{k} p^k (1 - p)^{n - k} \cdot \frac{p^{\alpha - 1} (1 - p)^{\beta - 1}}{B(\alpha, \beta)} \, dp
$$
After some more math manipulations (moving the constants outside the integral, adding the exponents):
$$
P(X = k) = \binom{n}{k} \cdot \frac{1}{B(\alpha, \beta)} \int_0^1 p^{k + \alpha - 1} (1 - p)^{n - k + \beta - 1} \, dp
$$
This part is a bit tricky, but the above integral indirectly contains a Beta Function $ B(k + \alpha, n - k + \beta) $ itself:
$$
\int_0^1 p^{k + \alpha - 1} (1 - p)^{n - k + \beta - 1} \, dp
$$
$$
P(X = k) = \binom{n}{k} \cdot \frac{B(k + \alpha, n - k + \beta)}{B(\alpha, \beta)}
$$
Putting it all together, we get:
$$
P(X = k) = \binom{n}{k} \cdot \frac{B(k + \alpha, n - k + \beta)}{B(\alpha, \beta)}
$$
And this matches the Wikipedia formula.
Did I do it correctly?

No only the result is the same as in the Wikipedia, but also the derivation.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta-binomial_distribution#As_a_compound_distribution
I'm not sure what is the question here

I tried to do this myself without looking at the wikipedia version
